# php preg_match no result without echo

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to scrape some data from PDF files. I'm using class.pdf2text.php (found [here](http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a)) for that (with some in-house adjustments), all works fine, but I have this very strange situation. If I run the code like this:

```
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('invoiceView2.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
$pdftxt=$a->output();
preg_match("/Generated on.*/",$pdftxt,$bill_date);
var_dump($bill_date);
die();
```

nothing is returned `$bill_date` is null. If I run the code like this:

```
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('invoiceView2.pdf'); 
$a->decodePDF();
$pdftxt=$a->output();
echo $pdftxt;
preg_match("/Generated on.*/",$pdftxt,$bill_date);
var_dump($bill_date);
die();
```

Then all the content of `$pdftxt` is printed, and the `$bill_date` is an array containing the result of the preg_match. As you can imagine I have no intention of outputting the whole content, I only need to get the preg_match result...

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off.... the class class.pdf2text.php had an attempt to show progress of decoding the text which called a `flush(); ob_flush();` which off course made the things go south... Always triple check the code of whatever class/addon you use if it is not your own.